# Has it rained/been raining at all since?

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

I want to know if rain occurred occasionally in France since the last time I went there, which is February. I would ask " Has it rained at all in France since February?". Is this correct?

Could I also say: "Has it rained in France since February?" or does this imply it has rained most of the time since February?

I am not looking for how many times it has rained, I just want to know if any rain has occurred.

Comment: Two possible constructions are 1: *Has it rained [**at all**] since last Sunday?* and 2: *Has it been raining [**ever**] since last Sunday?,* where #1 implies *on at least one occasion*, and #2 implies *most of the time / continuously*. If included, the optional highlighted elements more strongly emphasise that distinction.

Comment: You should only say: Has it rained in France since February? Because: "Did it rain since February." is not grammatical at all. Did she eat since yesterday? [Buzzer]. Has she eaten since yesterday? [No buzzer]

Comment: It would be strange to ask this.  France is a big place and it gets a normal amount of rain.  It would be remarkable if there had been no rain at all anywhere in France.

Answer (score 1):

Both "Has it rained at all in France since February" and "Has it rained in France since February" are grammatically correct and match your intention/purpose; I recommend you go with the first sentence for clarification that you are trying to find out if *any* rain has occurred, because going with the latter may be interpreted as "has it generally rained/often rained since then".